# PyQt --> addItem --> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'chatbox.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
import sys, socket
from threading import *
import _thread

def app_version():
        msg_box("Application Version", "Test 0.1")

def msg_box(title, data):
        w = QWidget()
        QMessageBox.information(w, title, data)

def update_list(self, data):
        self.listWidget.addItem(data)
        print ("\a")

def server_socket(self):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 10420))
        s.listen(1)
    except socket.error:
        msg_box("Socket Error !!",
            "Unable To Setup Local Socket. Port In Use")
        return

    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        incoming_ip = str(addr[0])
        current_chat_ip = self.lineEdit.text()

        if incoming_ip != current_chat_ip:
                conn.close()
        else:
                data = conn.recv(4096)
                update_list(self, data)
                conn.close()

    s.close()



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.start_server()
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(860, 646)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 671, 31))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 331, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 61, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 0, 55, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 0, 171, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 401, 411))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 361))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 151, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        #############################################################
        # Executes When The Send Message Button Is Clicked
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.client_send_message)
        ############################################################

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 380, 151, 28))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        #############################################################
        # Executes When The Clear Logs Button Is Clicked
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.clear_logs)
        ##############################################################

        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 261, 421))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 401))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 860, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu_Action = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu_Action.setObjectName("menuMenu_Action")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionVersion = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionVersion.setObjectName("actionVersion")

        #######################################################
        # Executes When The SubMenu Item Version Is Clicked
        self.actionVersion.triggered.connect(app_version)
        #######################################################

        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")

        #######################################################
        # Executes When The SubMenu Item Exit Is Clicked
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        #######################################################

        self.menuMenu_Action.addAction(self.actionVersion)
        self.menuMenu_Action.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu_Action.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def clear_logs(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP address"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear logs"))
        self.menuMenu_Action.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu Action"))
        self.actionVersion.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Version"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    def start_server(self):
        Thread(target=server_socket, args=(self,)).start()
        msg_box("Success", "Server Started Sucessfully")

    def client_send_message(self):
        ip_address = self.lineEdit.text()

        nick = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        nick = nick.replace("#>","")
        rmessage = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        rmessage = rmessage.replace("#>","")

        rmsg =  nick + " #> " + rmessage

        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        try:
            c.connect((ip_address, 10420))
        except Exception:
            msg_box("Connection Refused", "The Address You Are Trying To Reach Is Currently Unavailable")
            return

        try:
                c.send(rmsg)
                self.listWidget.addItem(rmsg)
                self.textEdit.setText("")
        except Exception:
                msg_box("Connection Refused", "The Message Cannot Be Sent. End-Point Not Connected !!")

        c.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I try to make chat app base on https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/sploit-build-peer-peer-chat-application-python-gui-linux-0163617/

And get error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "D:\Program Files\python 3.7\lib\threading.py", line 917, in_bootstrap_inner 
self.run()
File "D:\Program Files\python 3.7\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run 
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
File "chatbox.py", line 47, in server_socket 
update_list(self, data)
 File "chatbox.py", line 24, in update_list 
 self.listWidget.addItem(data)
 TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
 addItem(self, QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bytes'
  addItem(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bytes'
```

I just begin code, so please forgive if having mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is received through `recv()` are bytes but `QListWidget` requires string so the solution is to convert it using `decode()`.

But your code has another hidden error(it seems to me that the author of the tutorial knows little about GUI so I recommend looking for another tutorial), the GUI can not be updated from another thread, that is forbidden by Qt, so the solution is to use signals or as in this case use `@pyqtSlot()` with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'chatbox.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
import sys
import socket
import threading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(860, 646)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 671, 31))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 331, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 61, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 0, 55, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 0, 171, 22))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 401, 411))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 381, 361))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 151, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        #############################################################
        # Executes When The Send Message Button Is Clicked
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.client_send_message)
        ############################################################

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 380, 151, 28))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        #############################################################
        # Executes When The Clear Logs Button Is Clicked
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.clear_logs)
        ##############################################################

        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 261, 421))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 401))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 860, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMenu_Action = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu_Action.setObjectName("menuMenu_Action")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionVersion = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionVersion.setObjectName("actionVersion")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP address"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear logs"))
        self.menuMenu_Action.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu Action"))
        self.actionVersion.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Version"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #######################################################
        # Executes When The SubMenu Item Version Is Clicked
        self.actionVersion.triggered.connect(self.app_version)
        #######################################################

        #######################################################
        # Executes When The SubMenu Item Exit Is Clicked
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
        #######################################################

        self.menuMenu_Action.addAction(self.actionVersion)
        self.menuMenu_Action.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu_Action.menuAction())
        self.start_server()

    def clear_logs(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()

    def start_server(self):
        threading.Thread(target=server_socket, args=(self,)).start()
        self.msg_box("Success", "Server Started Sucessfully")

    def client_send_message(self):
        ip_address = self.lineEdit.text()
        nick = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        nick = nick.replace("#>","")
        rmessage = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        rmessage = rmessage.replace("#>","")
        rmsg =  nick + " #> " + rmessage
        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            c.connect((ip_address, 10420))
        except Exception:
            self.msg_box("Connection Refused", "The Address You Are Trying To Reach Is Currently Unavailable")
            return
        try:
            c.send(rmsg.encode())
            self.listWidget.addItem(rmsg)
            self.textEdit.clear()
        except Exception:
            self.msg_box("Connection Refused", "The Message Cannot Be Sent. End-Point Not Connected !!")
        c.close()

    def app_version(self):
        self.msg_box("Application Version", "Test 0.1")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def msg_box(self, title, data):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, title, data)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_list(self, data):
        self.listWidget.addItem(data)
        print("\a")

def server_socket(self):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 10420))
        s.listen(1)
    except socket.error:
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "msg_box", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "Socket Error !!"),
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "Unable To Setup Local Socket. Port In Use"))
        return
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        incoming_ip = str(addr[0])
        current_chat_ip = self.lineEdit.text()
        if incoming_ip != current_chat_ip:
            conn.close()
        else:
            data = conn.recv(4096).decode()
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "update_list", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, QtCore.Q_ARG(str,data))
            conn.close()
    s.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the other hand I recommend using QTcpSocket since with its use there is no need for threads, in the this [link](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/network) you can find several examples.